# Distance between elements in a set & the number of elements in the set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, intuition

Consider the set of real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$. As far as I understand, it is a *metric space* in that it has a distance function defined on it $$d(x,y)=\lvert x-y\rvert$$ with $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Intuitively, $d(x,y)$ quantifies the "*distance*" between two numbers $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, given that $d(x,0)=\lvert x\rvert$, one can think of a number $x\in\mathbb{R}$ as being $\lvert x\rvert$ units of distance from the origin $0\in\mathbb{R}$ along the real number line.

Now, if one considers a *finite* subset of the real numbers, for example, $\lbrace 0,1,2,3,4,5\rbrace\subset\mathbb{R}$, then the distance between any two elements is *one less* than the number of elements *separating* them. By this I mean, for example $$d(5,1)=\lvert 5-1\rvert =4$$ but the number of elements *separating* them is 5 (if you count the end points).

My question is, for a *finite* set of numbers is there any relation between the number of elements *separating* any two elements in the set and the distance between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we talk of a set, we do not consider the order, so $\{0,1,2,3\}=\{1,3,2,0\}$ and you can't define the distance that way.  If you use parentheses instead of braces you get a sequence, which does specify the order of the elements.  What you are really defining is a distance on $\Bbb N$, where you are looking at the index of the element in a sequence.  This is the usual distance on $\Bbb N$

Your example depends on the fact that the numbers in your sequence are consecutive integers.  What is the distance between $1$ and $5$ in $(0,1,3,5)$?  You can certainly define a distance the way you suggest on any given sequence, but the distance between $1$ and $5$ will vary depending on the sequence.  In this example it would be $2$.

Comment: Sorry, I'd meant to refer to the set being ordered (hence discussing real numbers). The question originally arose in my mind when I was considering the ordered sequence of integers $(-10,\ldots ,10)$. I then partitioned this sequence such that the distance between two elements in the sequence was $0.01$. Naively, I thought that there would then be 2000 elements in the sequence (using that the distance between the endpoints is 20), however, upon further inspection I realised that there are in fact 2001 elements (it turns out I'd forgotten to count the end point)...

Comment: It made me wonder if there is a general way to correctly count the number of elements in cases like these?! In the example I gave in my post the sequence (0,1,2,3,4,5) would have a distance of 5 units between 0 and 5, however there are 6 elements separating them (if we include the endpoint).

Comment: This is called a [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error).  If you build a 10 foot long fence with posts on the edges of one foot boards, you need 10 boards but 11 posts.  Often you want to count one end and not the other.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't realise it was an actual phenomenon, I thought I was just being a bit stupid! Is this because, when one naively counts a distance along the number line one usually doesn't include the start point (for example, the number 5 is 5 units of distance from the number 0)?!

Comment: ... is the point that when we want to work out the *span* between numbers (that is, how many numbers separate them - the distance between them) we subtract the upper endpoint from the lower one. However, if we want to determine the actual number of elements in the range then we need to include both endpoints?! For example, the distance between floors 8 and 11 of a multistorey building is 11-8=3, but there are 11-8+1=4 floors. In, general, for a sequence with endpoints $n$ and $m$ would one say that the *span* is $\lvert n-m\rvert +1$?!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The plus one comes because you are counting both endpoints, while the distance only counts one.

Comment: Is the reason why the distance counts only one because one is counting how many units of distance a given point is from one of the endpoints?

Comment: .... Heuristically, there are $\lvert n-m\rvert$ unit intervals between the endpoints $n$ and $m$, which is equivalent to counting all of the points "sandwiched" between the endpoints plus the final endpoint (assuming the points are ordered), however if one includes the endpoint at the beginning of the first interval, then $\lvert n-m\rvert+1$ points.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help!